# How do I constrain a specific area of an actor to mouse X and Y?

Tags: gamesalad

I recently watched this tutorial "[Actor Constraints in GameSalad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=0_3yp8AP2iE)" detailing how to constrain the center of an actor to the mouse X and Y, but I would like to constrain the relative clicked pixel of the actor to the mouse X and Y, not the center of the actor.

In other words, I want to avoid the "jumping" nature of "constrain self.Position.X to game.Mouse.Position.X" when I click and drag.

Comment: Hi nipponese, and welcome to GDSE. Since your post is already tagged with 'gamesalad', and this will almost always appear alongside your question, you don't also need to dump the tag in your question title. I've edited it out.

Answer (score -1):

That's simple.  When the actor is clicked, store the difference between each coordinate and the (0,0) spot (wherever that might be) in a couple of variables.  Then as the mouse is moved and you move the actor, subtract those stored values from the mouse position to determine where the actor should be placed.

Note, I have no knowledge of Gamesalad in particular.  It does have variables right?

Comment: Note that when you have no knowledge of the technology the question is about, your answer is unlikely to be helpful.